# Why does converting a Measurement raise an error in swift?

Tags: swift

I have this code:

```
func convertUnit(val:Double, from:Unit, to:Unit) -> String {
    let a = Measurement(value: val, unit: from)
    let b = a.converted(to: to).value
    return b
}
```

When I try to run it, it gives me an error.

```
Referencing instance method 'converted(to:)' on 'Measurement' requires that 'Unit' inherit from 'Dimension'
```

I am calling the function from the content view like this:

```
convertUnit(val: (self.inputValue as NSString).doubleValue, from: UnitAcceleration.metersPerSecondSquared, to: UnitAcceleration.metersPerSecondSquared)
```

Could someone explain to me why the error is occurring and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're trying to use, `converted(to:)`, is declared in a specialized extension to Measurement:

```
extension Measurement where UnitType : Dimension {
    
    public func converted(to otherUnit: UnitType) -> Measurement<UnitType>
}
```

Thus, `converted(to:)` can only be used when UnitType is of type Dimension. You must either switch the `from` and `to` parameter types to Dimension:

```
func convert(_ value: Double, from sourceUnit: Dimension, to targetUnit: Dimension) -> Double {
    let a = Measurement(value: value, unit: sourceUnit)
    let b = a.converted(to: targetUnit).value
    return b
}
```

– or make your function generic, so that Type `T` inherits from Dimension. Then you can also constrain the source and target units, `T`, to be of the same type.

```
func convert<T: Dimension>(_: T.Type, _ value: Double, from sourceUnit: T, to targetUnit: T) -> Double {
    return Measurement(value: value, unit: sourceUnit).converted(to: targetUnit).value
}

convert(UnitAcceleration.self, 43.2, from: .metersPerSecondSquared, to: .gravity)
```

Comment: This does solve the question but why would you create a generic  method to convert from one dimension to another? IMO it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: If you use  the original method you would need to use the same unit type. i.e: UnitAcceleration.gravity -> UnitAcceleration.metersPerSecondSquared. With this generic method you can go from UnitAcceleration.gravity to UnitAngle.degrees and the result will obviously be wrong (it can't convert from one dimension to another)

Comment: @LeoDabus Haven’t used Swift in some time. Thanks for the comments. I must’ve forgotten a few things, since I thought the generic T would require the same Unit type for both arguments. I’m looking into it, and will update my answer afterwards. What original method are you talking about? All 4 methods (Q and A) allow going from UnitAccelerarion to UnitAngle, etc.

Comment: `Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitAcceleration.gravity).converted(to: .metersPerSecondSquared)` or `Measurement<UnitAcceleration>(value: 1, unit: .gravity).converted(to: .metersPerSecondSquared)`

Comment: @LeoDabus When wrapped in a generic function, parameters of `T: Dimension` are not required to be of the same subclass of Dimension, as this example shows: `func c<T: Dimension>(v: Double, a: T, b: T) -> Measurement<T> { let m = Measurement<T>(value: v, unit: a); return m.converted(to: b) }`